# How to pass parameters with value using @url.Action using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/GetAllSearchData",
    datatype: "json",
    type: "get",
    data: {
        text: Search,
        city: city,
        locality: locality
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.result != null) {
            $("#table").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
                var res = [];
                res = data.result[i].Id.split(",");
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + " <div class='dashboardmodal - body'><p><a href='@Url.Action("
                    SearchAction ", "
                    Home ", new { city = city })'>" + data.result[i].name + "</a></p>" + "</div></td>");
                $('#table').append(tr);
            }
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

I am trying to pass city variable value to anchor tag parameter but getting error `the name does not exist in the current context`

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is server side code (its executed on the server before the html is sent to the view) - your `city` variable is client side code and does not even exist at that point

Comment: Use `Url.Action()` in the `GetAllSearchData()` method to generate the url, and pass that back to the client in your `JsonResult`

Answer (score 0):

Better change the object name city to cityObj and then try passing the same ..
or just try the below one and check in console

```
'@Url.Action("SearchAction", "Home")?city=' + city +
```

or your could try the below,

```
'@Url.Action("SearchAction", "Home")', { city: city }
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: thanks its working but little bit correction is there

'@Url.Action("SearchAction", "Home")', { city: "+ city +" }

Comment: its working but result is not getting in correct format. 
Its getting like this

<a href="/Home/SearchAction" , { city:  pune,}'>Dr.SonaSingh Korekar</a>